# Oracle How can I split SELECT result?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tables and I want to separate/chunk each section by code column.

My current result:

```
Sent Date     code   emailsent
31/08/2021    0001   1  
31/08/2021    0002   2  
31/08/2021    0003   2 
31/08/2021    0004   2
```

Expected result:

```
31/08/2021    0001   1 
30/08/2021    0001   2  
29/08/2021    0001   2 
28/08/2021    0001   2 
----------------------   skipped 27th to 2nd records
01/08/2021    0001   2
```

Then the next batch is loaded as it's a new code and we do this until all code's are read per given month. And the count must always remain as I need to count emails as the core objective.

```
31/08/2021    0002   3 
30/08/2021    0002   9  
29/08/2021    0002   3 
28/08/2021    0002   10 
----------------------   skipped 27th to 2nd records
01/08/2021    0002   9
```

```
SELECT 
    TRUNC(E.DATE) "Sent Date", o.CODE "code", COUNT(*) "Emails Sent"
FROM 
    emails ec, orders so, office o
WHERE 
    EC.OID = SO.OID
    AND SO.CODE = O.CODE
    AND E.DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/AUG/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') 
    AND TO_DATE('31/AUG/2021','dd/mon/yyyy')
GROUP BY
    TRUNC(E.DATE), SO.CODE
ORDER BY
     TRUNC(E.DATE) DESC, SO.CODE;
```

What is this concept called?

**FIX I changed JUST the last line**:

```
TRUNC(E.DATE) DESC, SO.CODE;
```

to

```
SO.CODE, TRUNC(E.DATE) DESC;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements; the `INSERT` statements for your initial data; a complete description of the issue (Are you trying to `INSERT` extra data into the table? Are you trying to leave the data unchanged and `SELECT` it in a different format? Why is there suddenly a row for `2021-08-31` when the initial data only had `2021-08-30` as the maximum? Where do the email sent numbers come from and why is it `1` for `2021-08-31` and `2` for other days of the month when the original table only had a value of `1`?)

Comment: Thanks @MT0 I have fixed the above. It was to leave data unchanged and select in a different format I guess that's all different selects do and email sent is virtual column name that represents rows count in emails tbl but needed to join with other tbl - orders - to pull codes via the order id (oid).

Comment: and then from o.code pluck out the code. Can you please check again?

Answer (score 0):

The way I understood it, it is a **calendar** you need (because tables you have don't contain all dates). Something like this (read comments within code):

```
SQL> with
  2  calendar as
  3    -- quick & dirty first 10 days of this year's August
  4    (select date '2021-08-01' + level - 1 as datum
  5     from dual
  6     connect by level <= 10
  7    ),
  8  all_codes (code) as
  9    -- you probably have such a table; you need a distinct set of codes
 10    -- to cross join it to CALENDAR
 11    (select '0001' from dual union all
 12     select '0002' from dual union all
 13     select '0003' from dual
 14    ),
 15  emails (code, datum, emails_sent) as
 16    -- simplified; you don't have such a data, but - as you didn't
 17    -- post test case, I'm not going to recreate ALL of your tables
 18    (select '0001', date '2021-08-03', 9 from dual union all
 19     select '0001', date '2021-08-08', 2 from dual union all
 20     select '0002', date '2021-08-05', 1 from dual union all
 21     select '0003', date '2021-08-04', 7 from dual
 22    )
 23  -- final query
 24  select c.datum,
 25         a.code,
 26         nvl(e.emails_sent, 0) emails_sent
 27  from calendar c cross join all_codes a
 28    left join emails e on e.datum = c.datum and e.code = a.code
 29  order by a.code, c.datum desc;
```

Result:

```
DATUM      CODE EMAILS_SENT
---------- ---- -----------
10.08.2021 0001           0
09.08.2021 0001           0
08.08.2021 0001           2
07.08.2021 0001           0
06.08.2021 0001           0
05.08.2021 0001           0
04.08.2021 0001           0
03.08.2021 0001           9
02.08.2021 0001           0
01.08.2021 0001           0

DATUM      CODE EMAILS_SENT
---------- ---- -----------
10.08.2021 0002           0
09.08.2021 0002           0
08.08.2021 0002           0
07.08.2021 0002           0
06.08.2021 0002           0
05.08.2021 0002           1
04.08.2021 0002           0
03.08.2021 0002           0
02.08.2021 0002           0
01.08.2021 0002           0

DATUM      CODE EMAILS_SENT
---------- ---- -----------
10.08.2021 0003           0
09.08.2021 0003           0
08.08.2021 0003           0
07.08.2021 0003           0
06.08.2021 0003           0
05.08.2021 0003           0
04.08.2021 0003           7
03.08.2021 0003           0
02.08.2021 0003           0
01.08.2021 0003           0

30 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot . I noticed a few issues with my sample. 1 I didn't branches tbl as orders had that I already needed so need to join a third tbl. Also I got real data when I replaced the dual calls with my actual tbls. Finally if changed my Order By and keep same Group  By I got the desired result.

Comment: I couldn't not upvote or mark as answer but this answer was very useful. Thanks

Comment: Why couldn't you? There are buttons which allow you to do that.